# Is there any method to safe handle twice freeing memory by delete-expression?

Tags: c++

If in theory imagine a situation where, by chance or by mistake (either through carelessness, or due to lack of experience, etc.), the memory was freed twice using delete-exprssion (yes, a good developer will not allow this, in well-designed architectural solutions, but howewer) how to (can we, or is there any method to) safty handle the situation so that the application does not crash?

Comment: use smartpointers.....and instead of calling delete twice, dont call it at all :)

Comment: not in theory and even less in practice you should manually `new` or `delete` anything but use smart pointers or the like instead

Comment: Primarily you solve the issue by *not* having pointers or your own explicit memory handling. For example by using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of `new[]`/`delete[]`. If you need pointers then opt for [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory#Smart_pointers). And if you really need raw non-owning pointers wrap them yourself using [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization). And *test, test, test!*

Comment: the question is not how to avoid twice delete-expression, the question is: 
is there any method to safty handle the situation? (if it happend all the same)
is there any method to safty handle the situation?

Comment: You mean, what you can do once it occurs?

Comment: To that question the only answer is: No. There's no way of handling double-free once it occurs. The "proper" way to handle it is to not let it happen in the first place.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thank you!!!

Comment: Out of interest, which operating system are you targetting?

Comment: is it matter?
if yes: linux and windows!

Comment: @James: With Windows 10 for example you can add a vectored exception handler, and hope that your C++ compiler doesn't optimise aggressively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> so that the application does not crash

This is just a side-effect, an implementation detail of the real problem. Double deleting causes undefined behavior according to the standard.

There is no way to turn a program exhibiting undefined behavior back into one defined so no, there is no way to handle it safely.

---

Ideally you shouldn't be using `new` or `delete` at all.

Comment: what the hell? the question is not how to avoid twice delete-expression, the question is: is there any method to safty handle the situation? (if it happend all the same) is there any method to safty handle the situation?

Comment: @James And I answered that question. I said : No there is no method to safely handle the situation. Re-read my answer.

Comment: You're a side-effect.

Answer (score 8):

Smart pointers were invented to deal with this problem.

If an object `X` is owned by object `Y` then `Y` should have `std::unique_ptr<X>` instead of raw pointer. No delete needed, `X` will be cleaned when `Y` is destroyed (or it decides to release the pointer).

If an object `X` is shared between some objects then each of them should have copies of `std::shred_ptr<X>`. Again no delete needed.

The only thing you should think about is: who owns what and when?

**EDIT:** (to satisfy literal question) No, you can't do anything about it. Double delete is UB. The sixth circle of hell. Although you can try to catch segfault (which is often caused by double delete) this will only increase your torment because you are in an undefined space anyway. The only way to handle it safely is to get rid of it.

Comment: @SombreroChicken First of all: this is XY problem. Secondly you are nitpicking and you take everything literally. Finally: this actually helps unlike "you are doomed".

Comment: @ModusTollens I would agree for that example. Anyway, we're going way off track, it matters not, I'll remove my comments.

Comment: sorry, sometimes I write something in the hope of adding something useful just to realize i caused the opposite. Deleted the comment, I really didnt mean to critize or offend you

Answer (score 6):

The behaviour of `delete p; delete p;` is *undefined* unless `p` is `nullptr`.

Setting the deleted pointer to `nullptr` following the `delete` is one way: the C++ standard requires `delete p;` and `delete[] p;` to be a no-op if `p` is `nullptr`. In other words `delete p; p = nullptr; delete p; p = nullptr;` is well-defined.

But this can lead to untidy code.

Other than the facetious advice to take more care, using smart pointer classes such as `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` eliminates the need for explicit `delete`s.

Comment: You're untidy .

Comment: @Bathsheba, do you understand my question?

Comment: @James: I think so - don't you like the idea of setting the pointer to `nullptr`?

Comment: @Bathsheba i want to know, if in theory somebody do that (twice use delete-expression), can we safety handle it?
i kow how to avoid the situations like this? you know!
there is so much methodes to do this!

Comment: @James calm down a bit, your question is highly misunderstandable, becuase "safty handle the situation so that the application does not crash?" once you have a double free your applicaltion already crashed so you need to do something **before**, once it crashed it is too late

Answer (score 2):

There are situations where you may need to `new` and `delete`. "Just use smart pointers" can be a cop out in practice. Especially with legacy software. If you must `delete` an object, it's better to set it null afterwards, (and null check before deleting.)

```
someObject *myptr = new someObject;
..... elsewhere in code to free .....
if (myptr) {
    delete myptr;
    myptr = nullptr;
}
```

This ensures the object underlying the pointer is only deleted once.

Comment: You need to write `delete [] myptr`

Comment: If it were an array as originally in my answer, yes, but it's fine as is now as is.

Comment: Unfortunately, the conditions where a double `delete` are most likely are those in which there are several copies of the pointer; nulling one of them will do nothing to solve the problem (I've even seen code that nulls pointer members in destructors - must be a cargo-cult thing!).

Comment: No need for the `if`, since `delete nullptr` is a no-op, and the assignment likewise.

Comment: @TobySpeight Correct on both counts. The `if` is a habit I carry over from C since `free()` does not have that safety.

Comment: You must have a broken C library - `free(NULL)` is documented to do nothing.

Comment: Yes, and there have been several broken implementations over the course of time. Documentation doesn't always correlate to real world practice. At worst, you're wasting one stack frame. However, the major compilers simply optimize the null check away if you do add one since it's a very common idiom.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do it is to provide your own versions of `operator new` and `operator delete`. `operator new` gets memory by calling `malloc()`, and `operator delete()` releases it by calling `free()`. That's pretty much what the standard library ones do. But yours can do more. `operator new()` gets the memory, then adds the address that it got to a list of allocated addresses. `operator delete()` first checks whether the pointer that was passed to it is in the list of allocated addresses. If so, it removes it from the list and frees the memory. If not, it throws an exception.

You won't like the performance.

Comment: Just to clarify: the standard library `operator new` and `operator delete` *may* be implemented using `::malloc()` and `::free()`, but that's not required.  I assume that's what you mean by "pretty much".  I guess the performance will be similar to running the program under Valgrind (but without the uninitialized value tracking that Valgrind performs) or other checkers (Electric Fence? I've heard of it but never used it).

Comment: @TobySpeight -- yes, the standard does not require using `malloc()` and `free()`. But it explicitly requires that `malloc()` and `free()` do not use `operator new()` and `operator delete()`.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't do that. What you could do (as a good practice is):

```
char *some_pointer = new char[100];
// use the pointer
strcpy(some_pointer, "this is it");
printf("%s", some_pointer);
// ALWAYS NULL the POINTER after DELETE
delete(some_pointer);
some_pointer = NULL;
```

So, whenever you are about to allocate memory for a pointer you could double check:

```
if (some_pointer != NULL) {
   // allocate
} else {
   // THIS IS SOME KIND OF BUG, can't continue
}
```

Comment: i know how to work with pointers? i know what is smart pionters!
but the question is not how to avoid twice delete-expression,or something else the question is: is there any method to safty handle the situation? (if it happend all the same) is there any method to safty handle the situation?

Comment: See my [comment to Cinder Biscuits](/a/54905923) - in short, this fixes the easy case but not the hard one (where there are multiple places holding copies of the pointer).  The solution is to have a clear model of ownership (and smart pointers can make that easier).

Answer (score 0):

You can take ownership of memory management for a given type by overriding the `new` and `delete` operators. This is not straightforward (for example overriding for array allocation) and Scott Meyers Effective C++ books has some great material on this (Item 16 for example), but I believe in theory it would give you the ability to delete a pointer twice.

I am not sure what the standard's view on this would be so I suspect as many have already said about this area of the language, deleting the same object twice would still be Undefined Behaviour.

Still, for the sake of discussion...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>

namespace {
  class DeleteMeTwice
  {
      static std::unordered_set<void *> deleted;

    public:
      void * operator new (std::size_t count)
      {
        void * const result = ::operator new(count);
        std::cout << "Newing: " << result << "\n";
        return result;
      }

      void operator delete(void *ptr)
      {
        if (is_deleted(ptr))
        {
          std::cout << "Not deleting: " << ptr << "\n";
        }
        else
        {
          std::cout << "Deleting: " << ptr << "\n";
          ::operator delete(ptr);
          deleted.insert(ptr);
        }
      }

      static bool is_deleted(void *ptr)
      {
        return deleted.find(ptr) != deleted.end();
      }
  };

  std::unordered_set<void *> DeleteMeTwice::deleted;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    DeleteMeTwice * const ptwice = new DeleteMeTwice;

    delete ptwice;
    delete ptwice;

    return 0;
}
```

Running on OSX with `c++ Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)` returns:

`Newing: 0x7fc384c02ab0
Deleting: 0x7fc384c02ab0
Not deleting: 0x7fc384c02ab0`

Comment: thank you for your answer!
but i need something else, i dont need to avoid twice deleting, i want to know, is there any legal way (method) to safety handle if it happened?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I believe the code above is an attempt at demonstrating a "safe" double deletion - most notably the repeated `delete ptwice` lines.

Answer (score -1):

I fount the answer!
To that question the only answer is: No. It is undefined behavior.